# InstallShield: service name

Tags: installshield, service-installer

I have developed a service installer using InstallShield, everything works fine. Could you tell me if it is possible asking the user for the service name (if he wants to change it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't change any **service names** or run a service with any other context than **LocalSystem** if I could help it.

**Frequent problems with services**: **1)** running with an AD user account, **2)** changed service name, the service doesn't stop properly, **3)** it runs with an administrator local account, **4)** timeout issues whilst starting / stopping etc...

If you mess with the user account you may not be able to start/stop/uninstall/administer the service properly. This has to do with extensive impersonation being applied during Windows Installer installations and uninstallations with sections of the install running as LocalSystem and others in user context. Generally it works, but I sometimes see locking problems which Windows Installer does not necessarily handle gracefully. If you mess with the name you won't necessarily be able to locate the service from another setup easily. You may need to stop and restart the existing service to get the new one working beside it.

*I particularly dislike running services with **AD accounts** since this involves network connectivity. LocalSystem has full local rights - bad enough, but this is what a service is designed to run with.*

Comment: Thank you @Glyzhkof; previously I used custom actions(nant) for that purpose and not problems arose. So, I was wondering if there is any way to do the same using installShield.